# Can't kill Dr. Eva at the end of Priority: Mars with an imported ME3 character on Insanity

Tags: mass-effect-3

I imported my ME3 adept for another playthrough on Insanity and breezed through until I came up to the part where Dr. Eva is charging at the player character in slow motion. I'm using a Paladin V pistol to shoot her, but even 3 consecutive headshots only bring her down to about 10% health, at which point she kills me while I reload. How can I kill her without lowering the difficulty?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a known bug with using a high-powered weapon against her - you need to land multiple shots on her, not maximize damage dealt. You can try switching to another weapon (SMGs and assault rifles work well) to kill her. If none of your weapons have the rate of fire necessary to kill her, you will need to restart the mission or reload a save before using a workbench/grabbing a weapon so you can change your loadout.